# Why does my datepicker not show after clearing in iOS web view

Tags: html, ios, webview

```
<input id="travel_time" type="text"  onfocus="this.type='date'" value="<!--{$min}-->" />
```

First click, the datepicker will open, but select "clear". Click again, and the datepicker will not show again.

Does anybody can know how to get the datepicker to show after clearing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateformatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
self.job.date = dateString;
self.textFieldDate.text = dateString;
```

Comment: I had found the problem , the reason why the html5 datepicker do not show again is the value had reset to be null. Thanks for your help.